# FPDF - Other ways to call Header and Footer with Codeigniter controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, fpdf

I am new to FPDF and I am trying to make the header and footer change,
when I used

```
    function Header()
    {
       $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
       $this->Cell(80);
       $this->Cell(30,10,'Title',1,0,'C');
       $this->Ln(20);
    }
```

It has error that says

> 'Cannot redeclare header()',

so what Im asking is, is there any other way of calling the header and footer? like

`$pdf->header->SetFont('Arial','B',15)`

or something?

Here is my code, I copied it from the tutorial 2 of FPDF, I dont want it views, I wanted it in the controller so it can called all the time

```
public function tutorial2()
{
    $this->load->library('myfpdf'); 
    // function Header()
    // {
    //     $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
    //     $this->Cell(80);
    //     $this->Cell(30,10,'Title',1,0,'C');
    //     $this->Ln(20);
    // } -- the Header function that is normally used

    $pdf = new FPDF();
    $pdf->AliasNbPages();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
    //$pdf->footer->SetY(-15);
    //$pdf->footer->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
    //$pdf->footer->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$pdf->footer->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');      -- not actually a working, or is there another way?
    for($i=1;$i<=40;$i++)
        $pdf->Cell(0,10,'Printing line number '.$i,0,1);
    $pdf->Output();     
}
```

Comment: A very simple way would be extending your own PDF class from FPDF and then adding that header function in your class. By that way you can use header function something like `$pdf = new myExtendedClass()` and then `$pdf->header();`

Comment: @TejashwiKalpTaru it actually give me this error: Class 'myExtendedClass' not found

Comment: You need to create a new class and then extend it. Why in this world you are directly trying to use 'myExtendedClass'. Read my comment carefully. I will post an answer, then have a look at that

Answer (score 2):

Download the FPDF from the [website](http://www.fpdf.org/). After downloading the file, unzip it, you will find a folder named "fpdf181" (where 181 is the version of FPDF).

1. Now move this folder into "application/third_party" folder of
   Codeigniter.
2. Now create a new Library named "CustomFPDF.php" in "application/libraries" folder of Codeigniter. Copy the code below in this "CustomFPDF.php"

Code:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require(APPPATH . 'third_party/fpdf181/fpdf.php');

class CustomFPDF extends FPDF {

    public function header($family){
        $this->SetFont($family,'B',15);
        $this->Cell(80);
        $this->Cell(30,10,'Title',1,0,'C');
        $this->Ln(20);
    }

    public function getInstance(){
        return new CustomFPDF();
    }
}
?>
```

3. Now create a controller in "application/controllers" and use the following in your function where you are using FPDF:

   ```
       $this->load->library('CustomFPDF');
       $pdf = $this->customfpdf->getInstance();

       $pdf->AliasNbPages();
       $pdf->AddPage();
       $pdf->header('Arial');
       $pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
       for($i=1;$i<=40;$i++)
           $pdf->Cell(0,10,'Printing line number '.$i,0,1);
       $pdf->Output();
   ```

Comment: but can i edit this thing? like can i do public function header($family){ $this->SetFont($family,'B','15'); } ? and do this at the controller, $pdf->header('Arial'); ?